# Parse custom data by JavaScript regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I have input like below in a js variable `var str`

```
MZ 09/10/2020 Zvwi‡L AbywôZ MCQ Test G DËxY© cÖv_©x‡`i ‡ivj b¤^‡ii ZvwjKv t
(cÖKvwkZ djvd‡j †Kv‡bv Kvi‡Y †Kv‡bv ms‡kva‡bi cÖ‡qvRb n‡j KZ©„cÿ Zv ms‡kva‡bi AwaKvi msiÿY K‡i)
9007 1027 1028 1029
7038 8040 1054 1055
0058 3062 1067 1069
3078 7097 1098 1106 = 16 Rb Kvi‡Y †Kv‡bv ms‡kva‡bi cÖ‡qvRb 3457,00867,1122 jtukh $3308
```

I wanna parse only all 4 digit numeric values from 9007 to 1106 (before = 16 Rb) in an array.

```
[9007,1027,1028,1029,7038,8040,1054,1055,0058,3062,1067,1069,3078,7097,1098,1106]
```

I tried with `str.match(/\d{4}/g)` but it will give me all 4 digits numeric values and 2020, null and unexpected result also.

Comment: First, extract that substring with `var block = s.match(/9007[\s\S]*?1106/)[0]` then use your regex against `block`.

Comment: Match parts of 4 digits till 16 Rb and then split on a space `^\d{4}(?:\s+\d{4})+(?= = 16 Rb)` https://regex101.com/r/1mWmQJ/1

Comment: Values are not static. so that, I can not bind from 9007 to 1106.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's the predictable pattern? If it's as simple as "four digits with space on both sides", then you can use something like `/(?<=\s)\d{4}(?=\s)/` (using lookaround assertions stops any number's match from "eating" the space around it and preventing that space from matching for the adjacent number):

```
const t='MZ 09/10/2020 Zvwi‡L AbywôZ MCQ Test G DËxY© cÖv_©x‡`i ‡ivj b¤^‡ii ZvwjKv t\n(cÖKvwkZ djvd‡j †Kv‡bv Kvi‡Y †Kv‡bv ms‡kva‡bi cÖ‡qvRb n‡j KZ©„cÿ Zv ms‡kva‡bi AwaKvi msiÿY K‡i)\n9007 1027 1028 1029\n7038 8040 1054 1055\n0058 3062 1067 1069\n3078 7097 1098 1106 = 16 Rb Kvi‡Y †Kv‡bv ms‡kva‡bi cÖ‡qvRb 3457,00867,1122 jtukh $3308\n'
console.log(t.match(/(?<=\s)\d{4}(?=\s)/g))
[
  '9007', '1027', '1028',
  '1029', '7038', '8040',
  '1054', '1055', '0058',
  '3062', '1067', '1069',
  '3078', '7097', '1098',
  '1106'
]
```

If the pattern isn't so simple, then of course the solution won't be either. It depends on what you can assume about the text.

Also, if this is client-side code, be aware that some browsers (e.g. Safari) still don't support lookbehind assertions like `(?<=\s)`, and even those that support it do so only in their more recent versions, since the feature was only added to the language in the ES2018 specification.

You could get away with using only lookahead and allowing the preceding space to be consumed by the regex, but then you'll want to use a capture group so that the space isn't part of the returned match, which means you have to use `matchAll` instead of `match` and grab the capture group from each result. So this slightly more complicated expression works in more browsers:

```
Array.from(t.matchAll(/\s(\d{4})(?=\s)/g)).map(m => m[1])
```

Either way, what you wind up with is an array of Strings. Your example output has unquoted numbers with leading zeroes, so it's not clear if that's what you want. If you want an array of Numbers, you can get that by either adding a `map` call to the first answer or modifying the existing `map` call in the second:

```
t.match(/(?<=\s)\d{4}(?=\s)/g).map(Number)
//or
Array.from(t.matchAll(/\s(\d{4})(?=\s)/g)).map(m => Number(m[1]))
```

Which in your example gets you this array of numeric values:

```
[
  9007, 1027, 1028, 1029,
  7038, 8040, 1054, 1055,
    58, 3062, 1067, 1069,
  3078, 7097, 1098, 1106
]
```

Comment: But that matches all 4 digits in the text surrounded by whitespace chars, and it would not match only 4 digits at the start of the string.

Comment: In `16 Rb` where `16` is the count of all 4 digit number. Your solution works fine until `999 Rb` up to 3 digit count. When the count reaches 4 digits then it'll include 4 digit Rb number also. @mark-reed

Answer (score 1):

You could match parts of 4 digits from the start of the string and then split on whitespace chars.

```
^\d{4}(?:\s+\d{4})+(?= = \d+ Rb\b)
```

- `^` Start of string
- `\d{4}` Match 4 digits
- `(?:\s+\d{4})+` Repeat matching 1+ whitespace chars and 4 digitd
- `(?= = \d+ Rb\b)` Positive lookahead, assert what is directly at the right is a space, `=` 1+ digits and `Rb`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7HGM9d/1)

```js
    const regex = /^\d{4}(?:\s+\d{4})+(?= = \d+ Rb\b)/gm;
    const str = `MZ 09/10/2020 Zvwi‡L AbywôZ MCQ Test G DËxY© cÖv_©x‡\`i ‡ivj b¤^‡ii ZvwjKv t
(cÖKvwkZ djvd‡j †Kv‡bv Kvi‡Y †Kv‡bv ms‡kva‡bi cÖ‡qvRb n‡j KZ©„cÿ Zv ms‡kva‡bi AwaKvi msiÿY K‡i)
9007 1027 1028 1029
7038 8040 1054 1055
0058 3062 1067 1069
3078 7097 1098 1106 = 16 Rb Kvi‡Y †Kv‡bv ms‡kva‡bi cÖ‡qvRb 3457,00867,1122 jtukh \$3308`;
    console.log(str.match(regex)[0].split(/\s+/));
```

Comment: `16 Rb` not static value. 16 is the count of all 4 digit number.

Comment: @Akashkhan Then use `^\d{4}(?:\s+\d{4})+(?= = \d+ Rb\b)` See https://regex101.com/r/7HGM9d/1

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
const str = 'MZ 09/10/2020 Zvwi‡L AbywôZ MCQ Test G DËxY© cÖv_©x‡`i ‡ivj b¤^‡ii ZvwjKv t (cÖKvwkZ djvd‡j †Kv‡bv Kvi‡Y †Kv‡bv ms‡kva‡bi cÖ‡qvRb n‡j KZ©„cÿ Zv ms‡kva‡bi AwaKvi msiÿY K‡i) 9007 1027 1028 1029 7038 8040 1054 1055 0058 3062 1067 1069 3078 7097 1098 1106 = 16 Rb Kvi‡Y †Kv‡bv ms‡kva‡bi cÖ‡qvRb 3457,00867,1122 jtukh $3308';

var n = str.indexOf("9007");
var s = str.indexOf("1106");

var res = str.substring(n, s).trim();
var data = res.split(" ");
```